# Adding a url.action to a anchor tag using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a url.action method to an anchor tag dynamically but for some reason it keeps adding a space between the url.action part and my action name.

here is the javascript code:

`var contentString = '<h3 class="info-window-title">Name of NPO</h3>' + '<a href="@Url.Action("Wallet","Wallet")">Click me to donate!</a>';`

here is the code once i inspect the anchor tag using chrome dev tools:

`<a href="@Url.Action(" wallet","wallet")">Click me to donate!</a>`

It keeps adding a space before wallet and i have no idea why. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see some problem in string concatenation, you have to use backslash character for double quote /single quote  inside string literal

```
 var contentString = '<h3 class="info-window-title">Name of NPO</h3>' + 
     '<a href=\"@Url.Action(\'Wallet\',\'Wallet\')\">Click me to donate!</a>';
```